# Convert Windows to IANA timezone in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, windows, timezone, iana

I am in process of migrating data and there is a requirement to read the timezone value in windows format and convert to its equivalent in IANA format. As per my google searches, it can be done via C# or Python but I am trying to accomplish this within SQL Server.
Are their any builtin functions that I can use to do this?

Comment: Just create a mapping table (as shown in duplicate link) and a function to query it.